# Is it safe to call OpenSSL BIO/EC_KEY/EVP_KEY/..._free functions on nullptr?

Tags: c++, openssl, unique-ptr

I have a ton of OpenSSL resources in the little app I'm writing. I usually wrap them in a unique_ptr with custom deleter, e.g.:

```
std::unique_ptr<BIO, decltype(&BIO_free)> bio(BIO_new(), BIO_free);
```

Now, this is straightfoward and tidy.

However, sometimes I need to operate on a raw pointer instead, and only when some processing finishes encapsulate it within a unique_ptr

```
BIO* bioRaw;
std::unique_ptr<BIO, decltype(&BIO_free)> bio(bioRaw, BIO_free);
```

Do I need to check if bioRaw is nullptr? Or will BIO_free (and the family of _free functions from OpenSSL) behave OK with nullptr?

Comment: some sources I've found (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-32/src/crypto/ec/ec_key.c and http://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-16/openssl/crypto/bio/bss_bio.c) suggest it is indeed safe, as the functions perform the checks themselves

Comment: You also need to be careful if you assign the pointer via an openssl function/macro, e.g. EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(private_key, r.get()); because now you need to make sure unique_ptr does not free r, but you can't stop it -- even assigning NULL to r will free the old value; so you would use the *_set1_* functions.

Comment: or, of course, you should assign with r.release() which provides the pointer and stops managing it and won't free it at the end

Comment: There are also several functions taking a pointer to pointer in OpenSSL. For those to work with unique_ptr, one has to r.release() (as Sam suggested), call the OpenSSL, then optionally set the unique_ptr again. In other words, take the raw pointer out for a while... which can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://www.openssl.org/news/cl110.txt) it is safe in version 0.9.2b, and so presumably safe in later versions:

> Changes between 0.9.1c and 0.9.2b  [22 Mar 1999]
>
> .....
>
> *) Make *all* *_free functions accept a NULL pointer.
>        [Frans Heymans ]

Note: it looks like this behaviour was [removed and
reimplemented](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/5761) because of a
licencing issue, but I don't think any releases were made between the removal
and the reimplementation.

Comment: Thank you for this, seems like this is the best confirmation we can get.